$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{2\epsilon}{\pi(x^2+\epsilon^2)}=\delta_0$ in the sense of distribution

Prove that, $\displaystyle\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{2\epsilon}{\pi(x^2+\epsilon^2)}\overset{\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)}{==}\delta_0$.

$\color{red}{\text{I'm not sure that the exercise is true.}}$ I think maybe it shouldn't equal to $\delta_0$ but $2\delta_0$.
I know the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2\epsilon}{\pi(x^2+\epsilon^2)}=\frac2\pi\arctan\frac x \varepsilon\big|^{+\infty}_{-\infty}=2$. So I think we can consider it in sense of Weighted Average. When $\varepsilon\to0$, almost all of the weights are concentrated at $0$. And realize $\delta_0$ as a average with weight only at $0$. It's an intuitive understanding, but I'm not quite able to write a rigorous process, so how do I describe the solution?

Compute $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\Bbb R} \frac{2 \varepsilon}{\pi(x^2+\varepsilon^2)} \varphi(x) dx$, unless I'm making a mistake the limit should be $2\delta_0$

Yes, the $2$ is incorrect.

@TedShifrin, why should $,2\delta_0$ be incorrect ? In my opinion it is correct.

Sorry. I meant the $2$ on the left-hand side of the original limit does not belong there.

@TedShifrin, yes, I looked through another document with this problem. And "2" on LHS doesn't appear. Thanks.

Let $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty} (\Bbb R)$, consider the following integral:
$$\int_{\Bbb R}  \frac{2\varepsilon}{\pi(x^2 +\varepsilon^2)}\varphi(x) \mathrm dx=\frac{2\varepsilon}{\pi} \int_{\Bbb R}  \frac{\varphi(x)}{x^2+\varepsilon^2} \mathrm dx \overset{x=\varepsilon y}{=} \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{\Bbb R}  \frac{\varphi(\varepsilon y)}{1+y^2} \mathrm dy$$
By the dominated convergence theorem, you have:
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{\Bbb R}  \frac{\varphi(\varepsilon y)}{1+y^2} \mathrm dy =\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{\Bbb R}  \frac{\varphi(0)}{1+y^2} \mathrm dy=2 \varphi(0)= \langle 2\delta_0, \varphi\rangle$$
